# Numerical solution 1st order ODE with Euler's method

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

I'm trying to solve this 1st order ODE numerically by bringing it into an explicit form, but I don't think it is valid because of the dependency on x_n in the final expression.

$$
\frac{d y}{d x} + x = 0 \\
\frac{d y}{d x} = -x \\
$$

Alpha is the angle from point with index (n) to point with index (n+1).

$$
tan(\alpha) = \frac{dy}{dx} \\
tan(\alpha_{n}) = -x_{n} \\
$$

I call h the step size.

$$
tan(\alpha_{n}) = \frac{y_{n}-y_{n-1}}{x_{n}-x_{n-1}} \\
tan(\alpha_{n}) = \frac{y_{n}-y_{n-1}}{h} \\
$$

When I rearrange this I obtain the following form.

$$
y_{n} = y_{n-1} + h\cdot tan(\alpha_{n}) \\
y_{n} = y_{n-1} + h\cdot (-x_{n}) \\
y_{n} = y_{n-1} - h\cdot x_{n}
$$

Is this the final numerical solution of this 1st order ODE?
$$
y_{n} = y_{n-1} - h\cdot x_{n} \\
$$

EDIT:
I've brought it to a better form I think.
$$
y_{1} = y_{0} - h\cdot x_{1} \\
y_{2} = y_{1} - h\cdot x_{2} = y_{0} - h\cdot x_{1} - h\cdot x_{2} \\
y_{3} = y_{2} - h\cdot x_{3} = y_{0} - h\cdot x_{1} - h\cdot x_{2} - h\cdot x_{3}\\
$$

So that the final solution is the following.
$$
y_{n} = y_{0} - h\cdot (x_{1} + ... + x_{n}) \\
$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your choice of assigning a time to the slope you get the implicit Euler method for a differential equation $y'(x)=f(x,y(x))$,
$$
y_n=y_{n-1}+h·f(x_n,y_n)
$$
The more basic explicit Euler method has the formula$$
y_n=y_{n-1}+h·f(x_{n-1},y_{n-1})
$$
so that the next value is computed from the already known value $y_{n-1}$

Comment: So in my case y_n = y_0 - h * sum[i=1, n](x_i) ?

Comment: Yes, for the implicit Euler method.. The explicit Euler method has $y_n=y_0-h·\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}x_i$.. Staying with the implicit method and since $x_k=x_0+k·h$, one can further simplify as in $$h·\sum_{i=1}^n x_i = h·n·(x_0+(n+1)/2·h) = (x_n-x_0)·(x_n+x_0+h)/2 =...$$